# Can SimpleSAMLphp have dynamic authentication source values?

Tags: php, authentication, single-sign-on, simplesamlphp

How can I set dynamic authentication source parameters? For example, how can I set parameters like `hostname` and `dnpattern` dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can. `authsources.php` is a `php` file so you can write a program, call external methods, etc from the file in addition to returning the expected configuration array. We've varied the `authsource` configuration based on hostname.